# PHP - Parse JSON Response

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse this JSON CURL response. I have tried json_encode, json_decode, serialize, unserialize. This is the raw response from CURL:

```
    {
    d: "[{"BranchName":"D7","BranchCode":"D7","Available":"0","StorageOnlySalesCenterMsg":null,"IsRestricted":false},
         {"BranchName":"A4","BranchCode":"A4","Available":"0","StorageOnlySalesCenterMsg":null,"IsRestricted":false},
         {"BranchName":"525A","BranchCode":"525A","Available":"0","StorageOnlySalesCenterMsg":null,"IsRestricted":false}]"
    }
```

I would like to just do a simple foreach statement like this:

```
foreach($json as $data){
    echo 'Branch: ' . $data['BranchName'] . ', ';
}
```

Result:

```
Branch: D7,
Branch: A4,
Branch: 525A,
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The JSON is invalid. It looks like an attempted JSON string inside of another JSON string, but since the inside quotes are not escaped, it's breaking the format. Talk to whoever you're getting the response from, and have them fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As aynber already pointed out, this would be a valid representation of your json object:

```
{
"d": [{
        "BranchName": "D7",
        "BranchCode": "D7",
        "Available": "0",
        "StorageOnlySalesCenterMsg": null,
        "IsRestricted": false
    },
    {
        "BranchName": "A4",
        "BranchCode": "A4",
        "Available": "0",
        "StorageOnlySalesCenterMsg": null,
        "IsRestricted": false
    },
    {
        "BranchName": "525A",
        "BranchCode": "525A",
        "Available": "0",
        "StorageOnlySalesCenterMsg": null,
        "IsRestricted": false
    }
]
}
```